# Cannot add favicon in Blogger

Tags: html

I am using a third-party template in Blogger and favicon option not showing in Layout. I have used this code but not working

```
]]></b:skin>

<link href='https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49497319651_bd2f1deb42_m.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/png'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make or design a 16*16 pixel image in a .png format then use one of the following snippets for adding the favicon itself:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png"/>
```